# Microsoft Graph SDK - fails while trying to get sharepoint files/folder info for External users

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We are trying to build a .NET application (C#) using graph SDK to view, upload and download files from the Share Point sites users has access to (Shared in SharePoint). External users with Microsoft online account (Personal) is invited in Azure AD as guest user and signed up. All internal users are already in Azure AD. I use Delegated user permission (On Behalf Of user access token) to pass to graph. I can get get the file/folder info from Share Point site, upload/download files to/from SharePoint ONLY as internal user. When I try the same, I get access denied. Checked all permissions within azure AD for graph API, and SharePoint access for external user. All seems fine, external user can login to SharePoint site and view/edit/upload/download file as well. Any one had same issues with external users while calling graph SDK?

Comment: Did you try to decode the access token for external users to call graph api? I think the token may give the answer.

Comment: @TinyWang Thanks for your suggestion. Yes checked the external user access token. It is using delegated user permission, and has the same scope (defined in Azure AD) as for Internal users. Internal users works fine with the scope (it has full access for sharepoint)

Comment: Thank you sir for your response, then I want to double confirm that if you tried to let external users use token generated by internal users, if tried to let internal users use tokens generated by external users? In my humble opinion, it should work you when the scopes is ok, as the external users has been invited to your tenant...